# How do I use PyPDF2 to read and display the contents of my PDF when ran?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I have a dummy pdf that has words on it. The course I am using to learn uses PyPDF2 on python. Is there a way for PyPDF2 to actually read the words on the pdf rather than give me objects?

This is the code I have so far that isn't giving me the results I want:

```
import PyPDF2

with open('dummy.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PDFReader(file)
    print(reader)
```

Output:

> <PyPDF2._reader.PdfReader object at 0x10efb1910>

Comment: pypdf2 is deprecated. Use pypdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract text from the PDF pages using `extract_text`:

```
import PyPDF2

with open('dummy.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)

    for page in reader.pages:
      print(page.extract_text())
```

Check the documentation [here](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/extract-text.html)

Answer (score 1):

Following code will give you text instead of object

```
import PyPDF2

with open('dummy.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file)
    #print(reader)

    for page in reader.pages:
        text = page.extract_text()
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a good idea so far, but you're calling the variable `reader` and not the text within the file.

You need to `iterate` through each page IF there are multiple pages, or just extract the text from the single page.

You can follow the documentation and it will give you examples with easy to follow explanations.

[PyPDF2 - Extract Text](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/extract-text.html)